# How to show scrollviewer for Teechart .net which moves the trend lines back and forth in teechart

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, teechart

I am working on Steema teechart control for .Net Visual studio 2010.
I am able to scroll the teechart graph using bottom axis arrow marks.
But my requirement is to show scrollviewer for the teechart by which scrolling should effect the teechart graph.
Teechart graph lines should move based on the scrollviewer movement.

I am not finding the exact solution Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you taking a look in the [Steema Forums](http://www.teechart.net/support/), concretely in this [thread](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14015) where I have answered a similar question of your and I think can help you.

Thanks,